# How to link object files and libraries without using makefile

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, libraries, object-files

I would like to be able to compile a c++ source file without using a makefile. And here is a prototype of my problem... I have the following `.cpp` file

```
// special libraries to include
#include "acado.h"  
#include "auxiliary_functions.c" 
/* -------------------------- */
// Create objects for special classes 
   ACADOvariables acadoVariables; 
   ACADOworkspace acadoWorkspace;

int main(){
    // perform task A_1
    // perform task A_2 
    // Tasks A_1 and A_2 depend on the specially included headers
    return 0;
}
```

and in the same directory I have the following makefile that allows me to compile the `.cpp` file successfully

```
LDLIBS = -lm 
CXXFLAGS = -O3 -finline-functions -I. -I./qpoases/INCLUDE -I./qpoases/SRC
CFLAGS = -O3
CC     = g++

OBJECTS = \
    ./qpoases/SRC/QProblemB.o       \
    ./qpoases/SRC/Bounds.o          \
    ./qpoases/SRC/Constraints.o     \
    ./qpoases/SRC/SubjectTo.o       \
    ./qpoases/SRC/Indexlist.o       \
    ./qpoases/SRC/CyclingManager.o  \
    ./qpoases/SRC/Utils.o           \
    ./qpoases/SRC/MessageHandling.o \
    ./qpoases/solver.o              \
    integrator.o                    \
    condensing.o                    \
    gauss_newton_method.o 

.PHONY: all
all: test libacado_exported_rti.a

test: ${OBJECTS} test.o

./qpoases/solver.o    : ./qpoases/solver.hpp
integrator.o          : acado.h
condensing.o          : acado.h
gauss_newton_method.o : acado.h   ./qpoases/solver.hpp
test.o                : acado.h   ./qpoases/solver.hpp

libacado_exported_rti.a: ${OBJECTS}
    ar r $@ $?

${OBJECTS} : ./qpoases/solver.hpp

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    -rm -f *.o *.a ./qpoases/SRC/*.o ./qpoases/SRC/*.a test
```

Now, for my purposes, I would like to delete this makefile from the `.cpp` file directory. At the same time, I would like to be able to compile the `.cpp` file ...

Knowing that the object files and libraries that the makefile refers to will be at their respective directories ....

So, everything I would like to do, is to compile the `.cpp` file without having a makefile.

Is it possible to do something like this for the given case ? ... If yes, your suggestions are really appreciated !

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Just reproduce the steps in the makefile manually.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if some of the people posting questions here are masochists. If it's not wanting to do things the hard way without using the C library, it's doing things the hard way without using make. Yes, you can do this by writing a script file that compiles all the files (every time, so it will take longer than using make) - just put all the commands that your makefile contains into a script file. If you don't like that idea, why not just typing it all in by hand?

Comment: Can you use another build system as long as it isn't make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your main() function is in the test.cpp, and you want the executable named "test" you can invoke the compiler directly from the directory where you would invoke make:

```
 g++ test.cpp -O3 -finline-functions -I. -I./qpoases/INCLUDE -I./qpoases/SRC -lm -o test ./qpoases/SRC/QProblemB.o ./qpoases/SRC/Bounds.o ./qpoases/SRC/Constraints.o ./qpoases/SRC/SubjectTo.o ./qpoases/SRC/Indexlist.o ./qpoases/SRC/CyclingManager.o ./qpoases/SRC/Utils.o ./qpoases/SRC/MessageHandling.o ./qpoases/solver.o integrator.o condensing.o gauss_newton_method.o
```